# Is It Right To Use Base URLs On Webpage

Tags: html, css, url, hyperlink

I am creating a web application, in which I have redirected URL from **"localhost/example/user.php?u=user1"** to **"localhost/example/user1"** through .htaccess, but when I open my redirected url with a trailing slash at the end like **"localhost/example/user1/"**, it disable all the css styles and images from the webpage. So to overcome this problem I am using Base URLs for including stylesheets, scripts, links and images into my website like `<style rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' src='localhost/example/stylesheet/style.css'/>`.

I want to ask that am I doing right or is it a bad technique to include links with their Base URLs?

Thanks

Comment: Go into your source code and open the stylesheet url by using right-click and you'll see that your path is wrong since you're not using absolute pathing, which you should for css files.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad technique. U can define variable `base_url` and use it in path. For example (if u use php):
in code:

```
$base_url= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/example/'
```

and in html:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' src='<?= $base_url ?>stylesheet/style.css'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

as it is, the url is interpreted as a relative uri. to make it absolute include the scheme

```
<style rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' src='http://localhost/example/stylesheet/style.css'/>
```

or start from `/` (this way you don't have to change the links when you go live)

```
<style rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' src='/example/stylesheet/style.css'/>
```